# place box on other image in matlab

Tags: matlab

i have image like:

[image]

i want like this[image]

my logic is that make 1st make box. And place that blak box on the picture but failed. any idea that would place black box on this picture????

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with a 'black box'? An overlay on top of the image or actually change the image? Also, what exactly have tried so far?

Comment: sorry for late answer as i lost electricity. i have placed the code

Comment: thats not happening on my code

Comment: Where is `Image` comming from? Shouldn't that be `I`?

Comment: it is already saved in matlab directroy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply need black boxes just set the intensity values of each channel to zero for the area you want. For example:

```
Image(30:70,100:200,:) = 0;
```

[image]

If you wish it to do it interactively you can use for example roipoly and first obtain a mask:

```
mask = roipoly(Image)
```

[image][image]

And then use the mask for each channel:

```
Image_r = Image(:,:,1);
Image_g = Image(:,:,2);
Image_b = Image(:,:,3);
Image_r(mask) = 0;
Image_g(mask) = 0;
Image_b(mask) = 0;
```

And reconstruct the original image

```
Image(:,:,1) = Image_r; Image(:,:,2) = Image_g; Image(:,:,3) = Image_b;
```

And here you go, beautiful Lena with a hole in the hat.

[image]

Comment: i need exactly like this. your topper one.

Comment: @user3440716 you're not doing what I wrote in your code, it's just one line :) If you want it to start in [w,h] and being big [r,c] you simply do: I(w:r,h:c,:) = 0. That's all, this line ;) (Don't forget to accept the answer if you solved the problem! It'll help people find the solution if they'll have your same problem)

Comment: if u are saying this , then its not occuring, only box printing.

Comment: ? That line of code change the intensities values of the image, therefore the box is now part of the image.  Is everything you need. I've generated the above pictures with that line. Believe me, it works. If not you're missing something. Can you post your new code with my line that is not working?

Comment: i have placed the code. plz have a look. I am also new in matlab

Comment: You're displaying only the box area of the image with imshow(Image(w:r,h:c,:));   If you simply do imshow(Image) it'll work. Consider looking at the matlab doc on matrices.

Comment: function image = q6_blk_square_wth_hw(r,c,h,w)
%UNTITLED9 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
I= imread('pout.tif');    %picture reading
imshow(I);
Image(w:r,h:c,:) = 0;
                %display picture
imshow(Image); end   ?????   same result

Comment: Your w,c,r,h are not yet defined where you display. You need to define w and c before... Please try a bit of effort on reading matlab error at least. Moreover be consistent with image name, if you load the image and name it I keep using it (not Image)

Comment: define means like this c= 10, h=1 ... ? then here is screen shot which i am doing in the way at: http://i60.tinypic.com/fyhnyf.png

Comment: Please read the full comment. " Moreover be consistent with image name, if you load the image and name it I keep using it (not Image)  " so everything that is called 'Image' replace with 'I'.

Comment: u saw the screen shots?

Comment: I did and there's still the error. Please show some effort reading at least.

Comment: can u edit my code so that i can see where am i making mistake?? i also changed "Image" with "I" . i thought it was data type

Comment: Umph.  I'm doing this, but please as general rule on SO. We're not here to write your code, you HAVE TO show some effort and you haven't at all. Copy paste this `function image = q6_blk_square_wth_hw(r,c,h,w)
I= imread('pout.tif');  
imshow(I);
I(w:r,h:c,:) = 0;
imshow(I);
end`

Comment: Note I've edited the comment above. Call the function properly and it will work. Accept the answer once you get it working.

Comment: i wrote this earlier and told u that now picture coming not black box. (Sorry bro for your kind help but i am failed with all steps i dont know why)

Comment: may be software problem

Comment: No. it's not you don't seems to be willing to understand. I'm screenshotting the right code with the right calls and with the right output.  I realised now that this is an hw stuff. I wouldn't have done this otherwise, but please UNDERSTAND what you're doing. Here's everything. http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=14e6vjb&s=8#.U0BrYvldVGM . Remember to accept the answer